# in laravel 8 I make simple relation between two model and after that when i get relation function no different values return

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I make simple relation between two model Offer(HasOne) and OfferType(belongTo). after that when i access relation function. function return below mention values

Offer model

```
class Offer extends BaseModel
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['title', 'slug', 'type', 'offer_type_id', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'status'];

    public function offertype()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(OfferType::class);
    }
}
```

OfferType model

```
class OfferType extends BaseModel
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['title', 'slug', 'image', 'status'];

    public function offer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Offer::class, 'offer_type_id');
    }
}
```

Relation access in controller

```
 public function index()
    {
        $offers = Offer::all();
        dd($offers[0]->offertype());
        return view('admin.offers.index', compact('offers'));
    }
```

My Output

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne {#263 ▼
  #foreignKey: "offer_types.offer_id"
  #localKey: "id"
  #query: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder {#1488 ▶}
  #parent: App\Models\Offer {#1499 ▶}
  #related: App\Models\OfferType {#1481 ▶}
  #isOneOfMany: false
  #relationName: null
  #oneOfManySubQuery: null
  #withDefault: null
}
```

Comment: try `dd($offers[0]->offertype);` `->offertype()` return function relation

Comment: i try this. but showing error

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'offer_types.offer_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `offer_types` where `offer_types`.`offer_id` = 1 and `offer_types`.`offer_id` is not null limit 1)

Comment: You can try this : `$offers = Offer::with('offertype')->all();`

Comment: offers vs offter_types : n-1 or 1-1 ??

Comment: Would you please post tables shema?

Comment: edit : `$this->belongsTo(OfferType::class)`

Answer (score 0):

if `offers` 1 - 1 `offer_types` : foreignKey - offer_type_id

```
class Offer extends BaseModel
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['title', 'slug', 'type', 'offer_type_id', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'status'];

    public function offertype()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(OfferType::class);
    }
}
```

```
class OfferType extends BaseModel
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['title', 'slug', 'image', 'status'];

    public function offer()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Offer::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: problem not solve with this

Comment: what does it show !?

Answer (score 0):

hi i think there is problem with you model relation

it should be like this

```
 public function offertype()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(OfferType::class,'offer_type_id','id');
    }
```

Then in your controller you can access like this

```
  $offers = Offer::with('offertype')->all();
```

i hope its works for you